# Access self inside closure returning type of individual class

Tags: ios, swift, closures, self

I would like to be able to access `self` in the following closure and always get the following error: `Value of type '(NSObject) -> () -> MyViewController' has no member 'pushViewController'`. I didn't manage to find a solution yet. Could you please help me and explain why I cannot access my current class or rather self?

```
//description view (try to use all the space... get length of text and adjust size accordingly)
let postDescription: PaddingLabel = {

    let entireDescView = PaddingLabel()

    //set properties of label

    //using library "ActiveLabel"
    entireDescView.enabledTypes = [.mention]
    entireDescView.mentionColor = UIColor(red: 25/255, green: 153/255, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    entireDescView.handleMentionTap { hotel in 
        self.pushViewController(of: hotel) //cannot access self here
    }

    return entireDescView
}()
```

Comment: Is this a compile time error or a run time error ?

Comment: Is MyViewController a `UINavigationController` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that closure is inside a computed property definition.

That definition exists *before* class or struct will be initiated.

You could fix it declaring `postDescription` as `lazy var`

```
public class User
{
    let postDescription: String = {

        return self.saludar() // Error. use of unresolved identifier 'self'
    }()

    internal func saludar() -> String
    {
        return "testing greeeting..."
    }
}
```

With `lazy var`...

```
public class User
{
    lazy var postDescription: String = {

        return self.saludar() // It's OK
    }()

    internal func saludar() -> String
    {
        return "testing greeeting..."
    }
}
```